# python TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am getting an error message when I try to run a python script, the python script I am attempting to run is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/orangetw/awesome-jenkins-rce-2019/master/exp.py I don't think that this is an issue with the script as I am able to run this on my host OS (having run the script in as OS)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exp.py", line 7, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    from urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 12, in <module>
    from cryptography import x509
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.base import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/base.py", line 18, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.extensions import Extension, ExtensionType
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/extensions.py", line 26, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.general_name import GeneralName, IPAddress, OtherName
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/general_name.py", line 16, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.name import Name
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/name.py", line 28, in <module>
    _ASN1_TYPE_TO_ENUM = {i.value: i for i in _ASN1Type}
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

line 7 is

```
import requests
```

Help appreciated

Comment: Running with ```python exp.py```

Comment: Hi there, Welcome to Stackoverflow! Make sure you're using the correctly associated version of python, I see you've tagged 2.7. Is that the version the code supports? Could you also provide the different OSs you've run this on and the results?

Comment: Yes python 2.7 is the version the code supports. Run from my host OS it outputs the required arguments. edit: Ran it on Debian 10

Comment: Usage:
    python exp.py <url> <cmd>